# MCPE chunks.dat to level.dat

Tags: minecraft, leveldb

I was searching in my old files and found a Minecraft PE world that dates from when the world was stored as chunks.db. I tried to open it using the latest version of MCPE but the game crashes. The problem seems to come from the chunks.dat file as it is not supported in 1.1.1. I searched on Google for a converter from chunks to level with nothing found. If anyone of you guys has a converter or knows one that works, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for your help!